# Incluir variable de sesion en consulta directa

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo esta consulta, necesito dejar los filtros variables, pero no se como incluirlo, para que la consulta lo diferencie como variable y no como un campo.

```
       $usercc = \Auth::user()->username;     

          $data = $this->paginateArray(
          $data = DB::select('select usuario_ad, count(usuario_ad) as conteo 
          from usuarios where usuario_ad in (select username from users 
          where users.refer=$usercc union select $usercc) group by 
          (usuario_ad)')
          );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En PHP lo que está dentro de [comillas simples](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php) `'` es interpretado como texto, por eso te toma el string literal `$usercc` y no el contenido de la variable.

Tenés 2 opciones.

**1) Usar comillas dobles:**

```
DB::select("select usuario_ad, count(usuario_ad) as conteo 
          from usuarios where usuario_ad in (select username from users 
          where users.refer=$usercc union select $usercc) group by 
          (usuario_ad)")
```

**2) Concatenar la cadena:**

```
DB::select('select usuario_ad, count(usuario_ad) as conteo 
          from usuarios where usuario_ad in (select username from users 
          where users.refer=' . $usercc . ' union select ' . $usercc . ') group by 
          (usuario_ad)')
```